# Solve a differential equation using variable separation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation:

$y'=xy^{2/3}$ with the initial condition: $y(0) = 0$

Here is my progress so far:

We separate the fariables: $\int y'y^{-2/3}dy = \int x dx$

Therefore, $\int y'y^{-2/3}dy = yy^{-2/3} + \dfrac{3}{2}\int yy^{-5/3} = y^{1/3} +\dfrac{3}{2}\int y^{-2/3} = y^{1/3} - 3\dfrac{3}{2}y^{1/3} = y^{1/3} = -\dfrac{9}{2}y^{1/3}$

**I know the answer to the problem, and I am supposed to find $3y^{1/3} = 3x^2+C$ which is obviously different from my result**

Comment: $y′=\dfrac {dy}{dx}$ And in your solutions you still keep the $y′$, erase that part, rest is fine.

Comment: I know for a fact that my solution is wrong though

Comment: The integration by parts would apply to $$\int y'(x)y(x)^{-2/3}dx,$$ not to $$\int y'y^{-2/3}dy.$$ Note that, due to the $y'$ factor, the meaning of this last integral is unclear, the most plausible interpretation being $$\int y'(x)y(x)^{-2/3}d[y(x)|=\int [y'(x)|^2y(x)^{-2/3}dx.$$

Comment: On a slightly more sophisticated level, note that any solution sheet suggesting that this equation is solved by a unique function $y(x)$ is seriously flawed. You might want to check that, for every $x_0\geqslant0$, the function $y$ defined by $y(x)=0$ for $x\leqslant x_0$ and $$y(x)=\left(\tfrac16(x^2-x_0^2)\right)^3$$ for $x>x_0$, solves this differential equation.

Comment: **One minute**: sure this is the proper delay to accept an answer on a subject you seem to have trouble grasping properly?

Comment: @Did yes, the mistake I made was really elementary, and Claude Leibovici neatly pointed what that mistake was (chillax!)

Comment: @aribaldi The truth is that Behzat and I pointed out what your mistake was.

Comment: @callculus Yes and your answer helped me indeed!

Comment: @aribaldi Yes the accepted answer points a mistake you made. And, as already mentioned, it passes over a more serious misconception, explained in my second comment. Re "chillax!", who is not chill and relaxed here?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

$$y'=xy^{2/3}\implies \frac{dy}{dx} =xy^{2/3}\implies \frac{dy}{y^{2/3}}=x\,dx $$ So $$\int \frac{dy}{y^{2/3}}=\int x\,dx \implies 3 \sqrt[3]{y}=\frac 12 x^2+C$$ Then $$\sqrt[3]{y}=\frac 16 x^2+C\implies y=\left(\frac 16 x^2+C\right)^3$$

Comment: This neglects the initial condition $y(0)=0$, see my comment on main for the reason why this cannot be omitted.

Comment: You have a typo in the last line.

Comment: @callculus. Thanks for pointing it !

Answer (score 0):

It is $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Therefore the equation is

$y'=xy^{2/3}\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} =xy^{2/3}$

Multiplying both sides by $dx$

$dy =xy^{2/3} \, dx$

Now you can go on with seperating the variables.

Comment: I  did that already I just didn't detail the part where I separate the variables

Comment: No you didn´t. You have $y' ,dy$ and $dy$ in one of your equations. Also $dy$ an $y'$ in another equation. For example here $\int y'y^{-2/3} \, dy = \int x \, dx$

Comment: yes, It is easy to integrate $\int x dx$ but I have to solve $\int y'y^{-2/3}$

Comment: OOOH I get it, thanks!

Comment: No, the left side is $\int y^{-2/3} \, dy$. because $y'$ has been replaced.

Comment: Nice the you get it. You´re welcome.